# Correct way to Reuse a NamedPipeServerStream in Byte Mode and Asynchronous

Tags: .net, asynchronous, named-pipes

I'm setting up a named pipe server and I reading from the Server Pipes... I have 5 possible concurrent connections allowed and they are setup like this.

```
Public Sub Start()
    Dim i As Integer
    While i < mTotalServers
        Dim s As New IO.Pipes.NamedPipeServerStream("IPSClient", IO.Pipes.PipeDirection.InOut,
                 mTotalServers, IO.Pipes.PipeTransmissionMode.Byte, IO.Pipes.PipeOptions.Asynchronous)
        i += 1
        Dim p As New PipeConnection(s, "Index - " & i)
        mServers.Add(p)

        s.BeginWaitForConnection(New AsyncCallback(AddressOf ConnectionReceived), p)
    End While
End Sub
```

I then resume operation until a connection is received.

```
Private Sub ConnectionReceived(ar As IAsyncResult)
    Try
        Dim p As PipeConnection = Nothing
        If ar.IsCompleted Then
            Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Connection received")
            p = CType(ar.AsyncState, PipeConnection)
            Dim s As IO.Pipes.NamedPipeServerStream = p.Stream
            s.EndWaitForConnection(ar)

            Dim conn As Connection = New Connection(p)

            While mRunning AndAlso p.Stream.IsConnected
                If p.ReadHandle.WaitOne(100) Then
                    Debug.Print("Set")
                Else
                    '
                End If
            End While

            If mRunning Then
                s.BeginWaitForConnection(New AsyncCallback(AddressOf ConnectionReceived), p)
            End If
        Else
            p.Stream.Close()
            p.Stream.Dispose()
        End If

    Catch ex As ObjectDisposedException
        ' Diagnostics.Debug.Print(ex.ToString)
    Catch ex As OperationCanceledException
        Diagnostics.Debug.Print(ex.ToString)
    Catch ex As IO.IOException
        Diagnostics.Debug.Print(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Once the Client end of the Pipe disconnects, I want the Pipe to be available for reuse.

The Part where I am Looping While mRunning and connected, is this how I should be doing it, or is there a better way? (my reading Code all occurs inside the Connection Class)

Also at the bottom of the block where I BeginWaitForConnection again, is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *...at the bottom of the block where I BeginWaitForConnection again, is that correct...*

No, it isn't. Once connected, an instance of `NamedPipeServerStream` is simply a `Stream` wrapped around a pipe instance connecting the server to a particular client. It isn't designed to be reused. Your code should just hand this instance over to your `Connection` object, which should ensure that it is disposed when the communication with that client is finished.

To reuse the "slot" in mServers which is freed up when a client connection is finished with, you need somewhere to instantiate a new `NamedPipeServerStream` and call `BeginWaitForConnection` on that. It looks as though your `PipeConnection` class might be the place to implement that.

Comment: One can reuse `NamedPipeServer` by calling it's `Disconnect` method (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.pipes.namedpipeserverstream.disconnect%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)